# how can i edit multiple objects/row atonce in django html template

Tags: django

i facing an problem on my django project . i try to edit and update an objects . but it's showing an error which is name is MultipleObjectsReturned .
hear is my issue screenshots .

when i was clicked this update button ( user can update which he went ) . than showing next 2nd image

1st img

[image]

showing this error

2nd image

[image]

Views.py

```
def purchase_order_item_update(request,order_id):
purchase_item_list = Purchase_order_item.objects.filter(order_id=order_id)
# porder = Purchase_order_item.objects.get(order_id=order_id)

# this is the form for getting data from html
if request.method == 'POST':

    for bt in Purchase_order_item.objects.filter(order_id=order_id):
        pu_id = bt.puid # product Id

    quantity = request.POST.get('asqty')
    unit_price = request.POST.get('uprice') # itemid = pk type
    total = int(quantity) * float(unit_price)
    cv = Purchase_order_item.objects.get(puid=pu_id)
    cv.quantity = quantity
    cv.unit_price = unit_price
    cv.total_price = total
    cv.save()
    return redirect('purchase_order_item',order_id= order_id)
return render(request,'back/purchase/assign_purchas_item.html',
              {'purchase_item_list':purchase_item_list, })
```

Actually i went to edit and update this list of entries and update also if user making any typing mistake then he can update .

thank you

Comment: You're looking for a Formset. I currently don't have time for an in-depth answer but formsets allow you to manipulate multiple models of the same type

Answer (score 1):

the error is pretty descriptive:

```
 cv = Purchase_order_item.objects.get(puid=pu_id)
```

returns more than one object. When using 'get' the ORM layer expects only one result, which is not the case you have. You most likely duplicated the puid value while testing. It happens often. In order to fix that you need to delete the second object that has the same puid, and ideally find out how you ended with two on the same uid value.

Comment: thank you dear . i didn't check the same puid . when i was solve it the issue is not solve . but now having one new issue . every time just modify only last added item . but not update old item . can you give me some sugestions ?